# Recurring payments and IPN notifications

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Can anyone assist me to understand and find answers to following questions:

1. When first notification (IPN) occurs for recurring payment. Will it be with initial payment or no?
2. Does `notifyurl` URL itself, which PayPal calls, contains some token for validation (i.e. `https://someurl.com/callback/[validation-token]`)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found interface ([link](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify)) to monitor those notifications.

Therefore now I can answer my question myself :)

1. Yes it does.
2. Looks like no. After I have setup notify URL from PayPal console ([link](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history)) my callback URL did not contained some suffix. Validation token itself is present in notification message

If you have any corrections kindly let me know.